# import cx_oracle fails when python script is started as win32 service

Tags: python, winapi, cx-oracle

I have written a python script that should run as a windows service by subclassing the `win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework`. Within the script the `cx_oracle` module is used.

When I run the service in debug mode ( `python DLOGprod.py debug` ) everything works fine.
But when I try to start the service ( `python DLOGprod.py start` ) importing the `cx_oracle` module fails with the error:

> import cx_Oracle ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I did have a look at the `cx_oracle.pyd` file with dependency walker and it reports about two  missing dll files `MSVCR90.DLL` and `IESHIMS.DLL`.

I am having the following setup:

- python 2.6.6
- pywin32-214
- cx_oracle_5.0.4-11g

Any help will be highly appreciated

mark

Comment: What's the `PYTHONPATH` when you start the service?  What's the value of `sys.path`?  You may need to write a tiny two-line service just to print the values to a file so you can share them with us.

Answer (score 1):

I did resolve my problem. The root cause was I had *only* added the path to the *oracle client software* to the **user's PATH** variable. Since adding it to the **system wide PATH** variable everything is working fine.

### To troubleshoot the issue I have followed the following procedure:

- downloaded the process explorer utility http://www.microsoft.com/technet/sysinternals/utilities/filemon.mspx
- determined the **PID** of my service ***sc queryex [serivce name]***
- filtered after **PID** within process explorered
- saw that **pythonservice.exe** could not find **OCI.dll**
- searched for **OCI.dll** on my system

At this point everything was clear.

mark

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please, when an answer solve your problem (even if it is yours answer) mark it as accepted (click the tick).